# WPF window slow when cold loading

Tags: wpf, performance, loading

My WPF application is taking 5s loading (hot loading, when the app has been already executed), but 20s for the first time (recently rebooted machine and so on).

Please, someone could post some tips about this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is what I was looking for:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many things that can go wrong. I would start with logging and performance profiling and then ask a more detailed question.

Comment: I have time profiling the time I can measure. It seems that the time is wasted inside the WPF framework.

Comment: If you can post more details people will be able to help you. Otherwise it's too little info.